# How should I read this piece of Scala (Play) code?

Tags: scala, playframework

I am new to Scala, and am learning it by going over some Play code. I have had a good read of the major concepts of Scala and am comfortable with functional programming having done some Haskell and ML.

I am really struggling to read this code, at the level of the syntax and the programming paradigms alone. I understand **what** the code is supposed to do, but not how it does it because I can't figure out the syntax.

```
  // -- Home page
def index(ref: Option[String]): Action[AnyContent] = Prismic.action(ref) { implicit request =>
for {
  someDocuments <- ctx.api.forms("everything").ref(ctx.ref).submit()
} yield {
    Ok(views.html.index(someDocuments))
  }
}
```

(Prismic is an API separate to Play and is not really that relevant). How would I describe this function (or is it a method??) to another developer over the phone: in other words, using English. For example in this code:

```
def add(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a + b
```

I would say "add is a function which takes two integers, adds them together and returns the result as another integer".

In the Play code above I don't even know how to describe it after getting to "index is a function which takes an Option of a String and returns an Action of type AnyContent by ....."

The bit after the '=' and then the curly braces and the '=>' scare me! How do I read them? And is the functional or OO?

Thanks for your assistance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's reduce it to this:

```
def index(ref: Option[String]): Action[AnyContent] = Prismic.action(ref)(function)
```

That's better, isn't it? `index` is a function from `Option` of `String` to `Action` of `AnyContent` (one word), which calls the `action` method of the object `Prismic` passing two curried parameters: `ref`, the parameter that `index` received, and a `function` (to be described).

So let's break down the anonymous function:

```
{ implicit request =>
  for {
    someDocuments <- ctx.api.forms("everything").ref(ctx.ref).submit()
  } yield {
    Ok(views.html.index(someDocuments))
  }
}
```

First, it uses `{}` instead of `()` because Scala allows one to drop `()` as parameter delimiter if it's a single parameter (there are two parameter lists, but each has a single parameter), and that parameter is enclosed in `{}`.

So, what about `{}`? Well, it's an expression that contains declarations and statements, with semi-colon inference on new lines, whose value is that of the last statement. That is, the value of these two expressions is the same, 3:

```
{ 1; 2; 3 }
{
  1
  2
  3
}
```

It's a syntactic convention to use `{}` when passing a function that extends for more than one line, even if, as in this case, that function could have been passed with just parenthesis.

The next thing confusing is the `implicit request =>`, Let's pick something simpler:

```
x => x * 2
```

That's pretty easy, right? It takes one parameter, `x`, and returns `x * 2`. In our case, it is the same thing: the function takes one parameter, `request`, and returns this:

```
  for (someDocuments <- somethingSomething())
  yield Ok(views.html.index(someDocuments))
```

That is, it calls some methods, iterate over the result, and map those results into a new value. This is a close equivalent to Haskell's `do` notation. You can rewrite it like below (I'm breaking it down into multiple lines for readability):

```
  ctx
    .api
    .forms("everything")
    .ref(ctx.ref)
    .submit()
    .map(someDocuments => Ok(views.html.index(someDocuments)))
```

So, back to our method definition, we have this:

```
def index(ref: Option[String]): Action[AnyContent] = Prismic.action(ref)(
  implicit request =>
  ctx
    .api
    .forms("everything")
    .ref(ctx.ref)
    .submit()
    .map(someDocuments => Ok(views.html.index(someDocuments)))
)
```

The only remaining question here is what that `implicit` is about. Basically, it makes that parameter implicitly available through the scope of the function. Presumably, at least one of these method calls require an implicit parameter which is properly fielded by `request`. I could drop the `implicit` there an pass `request` explicitly, if I knew which of these methods require it, but since I don't, I'm skipping that.

An alternate way of writing it would be:

```
def index(ref: Option[String]): Action[AnyContent] = Prismic.action(ref)({
  request =>
  implicit val req = request
  ctx
    .api
    .forms("everything")
    .ref(ctx.ref)
    .submit()
    .map(someDocuments => Ok(views.html.index(someDocuments)))
})
```

Here I added `{}` back because I added a declaration to the body of the function, though I decided not to drop the parenthesis, which I could have.

Comment: wow, thanks a million, that is an excellent explanation. Especially about the 'Haskell do notation'. There was I trying to find those methods in the api docs and failing. Thanks for taking the time to type all that!

Comment: @user3231690 By the way, I suspect the return of `submit()` is an `Option`, the Scala equivalent of Haskell's `Maybe`. So the for comprehension will either your `Some[Ok[???]]`, or `None`. Assuming I'm right.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

`index` is a `function` which takes an `Option` of a `String` and returns an `Action` of type `AnyContent`. It calls the method `action` that takes as a first argument an `Option` and as a second argument a method that assumes an implicit value request of type `Request` is in scope. This method uses a For-comprehension that calls the `submit` method which returns an `Option` or a `Future` and then in case its execution is successful, it yields the result `Ok(...)` that will be wrapped in the `Action` returned by the `action` method of `Prismic`.

Comment: so the Request object (is it an object or a function or what?) is in the Predef scope and is injected '=>' into the function as a parameter? that just looks bizarre and odd? I can't even work out if this is functional or OO....

Answer (score 0):

- `Prismic.action` is a method that takes 2 groups of arguments (a.k.a. currying).
- The first is `ref`
- The second is `{ implicit request => ...}`, a function defined in a block of a code

[more information on Action](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaActions)

Comment: That would be currying, or, more properly, schönfinkeling.